# Strange compilation error when Java Generic T is parametrized by different parameter types

Tags: java, generics

I was going through this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) provided by Java Oracle regarding generics. Now under section Generic Methods, it explains that Generic T can take different parameters at same time.

Example Code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object [] arrObjects = new Object[1];
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    String [] arrString = new String[1];

    fromArrayToCollection(arrString, objectList);  // Works properly
    fromArrayToCollection(arrObjects, stringList); // Gives compilation error

}

private static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : c) {
        a[0] = o; // Correct
    }
}
```

Here in the example fromArrayToCollection method call is right in one case, but throws compilation error in other case.

Also the link also says similar line

> We can call this method with any kind of collection whose element type is a supertype of the element type of the array.

It says collection element type should be supertype of array element but why not otherwise.

Comment: You'd have to change `Collection<T> c` to `Collection<? super T> c`

Comment: Because the actual examples in the documentation puts array elements in the collection (from array to collection, hence the name of the method), unlike your example, which puts collection elements into the array.

Comment: `fromArrayToCollection(arrObjects, stringList);` you pass object[] and List<String> where method calling is only `T` so T can be Object or String not both. replace `arrObjects` with `arrString` or create one More generic type `E`